# Recovering ext4 data after accidental partial re-image?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext4, file-recovery

I had a CD that automatically starts to image a system with windows XP/NTFS. Accidentally booted from it on a Linux system which has one large ext4 partition (500GB). Interrupted the imaging process after about 3-4 seconds.

I would imagine the file table is gone since there was enough time to write at least 100MB to disk. However, I have heard of some kind of superblock backup on ext4(?) Any software/process to recover the non-overwritten files from the damaged ext4 partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to give it a try.  The backup superblock should be intact, so boot from a live CD if the OS is toast, and run

```
/sbin/fsck.ext4 /dev/<thePartition>
```

If something more in-depth is required, then taking this step could make matters worse, so if you have space somewhere else, you could make a security byte level copy first to another disk with a partition the same size on it:

```
dd if=/dev/<thePartition> of=/dev/<aSparePartition> bs=1M
```

If your imaging process reparitioned the disk, then you can rebuild the partition table without deleting data with fdisk or parted, provided you know the layout that was used.